# Specific column not clickable

Tags: jquery, wordpress, datatables

I have a table in wpdatatables with a couple of columns, I'm looking for a jquery code to disable the click on a specific column. I can give a specific class of each column. Any idea is welcome.

That's what I'm trying.
It works but it is easy to overcome such limitations. I'm local, but here you can see a demo similar to my table. [Demo](http://sandbox.wpdatatables.com/editable-wordpress-table-demo/)

```javascript
 <script type = "text/javascript" language = "javascript">

$('#table_1').on('click', 'td', function() {
    alert('show popup'); 
});

$('#table_1').on('click', 'td:first-child, td:last-child', function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
});
</script>
```

Comment: Welcome.  Please share some examples of what you've tried so far so we can better help you.

Comment: you can inspect the element particularly that column have  any overflow issue.

Comment: I wish users could only change the first column